# Powershell return function manipulation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to read from windows registry editor and if the value read is correct or according to the hardening requirement I put down to `Good` else the `Bad`.

I wanted to add a statistical where I want to count all the `Bad` value and put it in a table to say these are all the registries with bad values.

But I am not too sure how to manipulate the function return, so I can collect these registries value and compile into a report.

```
$array = @(
    "PreventStorage",
    "RemoteAssistance",
)

function PreventStorage {
    $getvalue = get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" -Name "NoLmHash"

    if ($getvalue.NoLmHash -eq 1) {
        Write-Output "Good"
    }
    else { Write-Output "BAD"}
}

function RemoteAssistance {     
    $getvalue = get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance" -Name "fAllowToGetHelp"

    if ($getvalue.fAllowToGetHelp -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "Good"
    }   
    else { Write-Output "BAD"}
}

$location = Get-Location

If (Test-Path $path ) {
    $array | ForEach { ( Invoke-Expression $_)} | Out-File $location\copy_into_a_report.txt
}
```

Question: How can I add maybe a single liner or double liner to check if the return function is good or bad. and if it is bad write-out the registry which contain the bad value ?

I have tried to see by adding a variable inside the function and read the variable from the outside like this

```
function PreventStorage {
    $getvalue = get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" -Name "NoLmHash"

    if ($getvalue.NoLmHash -eq 1) {
        $new_variable = 'Good'
        Write-Output "$new_variable"
    }
    else { 
        $new_variable = 'Bad'
        Write-Output "$new_variable"
    }
}
```

and I have attempted the following

```
$new = $array | ForEach { ( Invoke-Expression $_)} 
foreach ($new ) | where {$new_variable -eq 'Bad' } | Out-File $location\copy_into_a_BADreport.txt
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your end goal is.  Why are you randomly invoking text?  What's the purpose of the registry reads?

Comment: So just as a side note, that is not really the idiomatic way to do that. Explicitly calling the functions is the way to go.

Comment: I am not invoking text. I cannot see where that is done. But I am invoking each function so that it get executed. that actually works fine. I have hardened the windows registries, and I have basically developed script to read each of the registry and check against what was expected, in this case if it is what was expected it return Good otherwise Bad.  What I am looking for is: When each function is executed, a registry key value is read . Ideally what I am looking for is  a way of counting how many time a function returned BAD.

Comment: You are invoking text when you call invoke Expression. Use & instead: `... | foreach { & $_ }`

Comment: Thank Bruce Payette, changed that.

Answer (score 0):

this issue can be closed, solved my own prob. Created a hashtable that stored key-value pair.